# Is it possible to install SSMS 2016 on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Need to install SQL Server 2016 Management Studio on a server. But on the server, SQL Server 2014 is installed. What can be done here?

How can we achieve this? Any detailed help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just install your SQL Server 2016 Management Studio ..... nothing special needs to be done. Since your server is still SQL Server 2014, you won't be able to use any new SQL Server 2016 features - like JSON support etc. - but it should **just work** out of the box ....

Comment: just do this. it will work

Comment: Sure! Thanks all.

Comment: Don't install SSMS on your server. It just encourages remoting into it, which is discouraged. Install on your workstation, and connect to the server.

Comment: I am installing 2016 now. When selecting features, shared feature directory and _shared feature directory (x86)_ are grayed out and taking different path which I am unable to change. Any idea why is it grayed out? I have kept SQL on path: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13'. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to SQL Server 2014 with SSMS 2016 but it won't be able to use the 2016 features with it.

Just download it from Microsoft:

**[Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)**

Comment: Above link gives version 17 for SSMS. Is there any link for SSMS 2016 please. Thanks.

Comment: It's just the latest version, do you specifically need 2016? Just Google it

Comment: Sure! Have few doubts, kindly help me here... I have 2k8, 2k12 and 2k14 sql server installed on the server. Additionally, have to install 2k16 as well. Will any conflict happen about the path or instance name (default or named)?.. Any possible scenario that might happen. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Its generally not a good idea to have multiple instances of SQL Server installed on the same machine, but it is possible as they will be stored in different directories. SSMS is the same, each version will be installed in its own directory so wouldn't cause that conflict

Comment: Thanks a lot...!!

Comment: To support this answer, I have SSMS 2016 installed and use it to connect to local SQL 2014 and SQL 2012 instances, remote (WAN) SQL 2014 instances, and Azure SQL v12 instances over the internet.  I have never had any problems doing this.

Comment: I am installing 2016 now. When selecting features, _shared feature directory_ and shared feature directory (x86)_ are grayed out and taking different path which I am unable to change. Any idea why is it grayed out? I have kept SQL on path: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13'. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: It's for the shared features and can be only chose on the first install. Once you have installed it any new versions just use that by default